# how to make branches identical

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a branch master in my repo `origin` and a branch `origRepo/master` (where `origRepo` is my upstream for `origin`, where I fetch always the changes from `origRepo`.
So far I have always been doing this to get only selective files of the commits in `origRepo`.
Basically a partial merge.
First I made sure that my master is clean with `git clean -df` then I

fetched from `origRepo`:

```
git fetch origRepo/master
```

then I merged without committing like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit origRepo/master
```

then I unstaged the unwanted files (**unmerged** denotes these files) interactively

```
git add -i  #interactively stage and unstage files
```

then I commited the merge (the selective files) with

```
git commit -m "Merged this and that"
```

Afterwards I reset to the commit and cleaned the master

```
git reset --hard
git clean -df
```

So far that went pretty well to pull in only some commits from origRepo/master

My problem is this: I thought apriori that the **unmerged** (unstaged) files during the above workflow (which I did for several commits of the history of `origRepo/master`) will always show up again when doing another partial merge (because those unmerged files are different from my master). But unfortunately they do not show up again ...?

The question how can I merge all **unmerged** files in `master` which I have **not merged yet** during the above workflow. Do I need to merge a whole range of commits again?
What do I need to do and was the above workflow stupid?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Your workflow is indeed **very** wrong. A merge commit in git says “I contain **all** the changes of both my parents”. (But as you already found out, it is of course possible to break that promise).

You are now in a rather horrible position, as git his no way of understanding what’s going on anymore. I don’t think git itself can help you here. I assume that you also made local changes that are only in master.

To fix this mess, you need to:

- checkout `master` and copy your working directory somewhere (**A**)
- checkout `origRepo/master` and copy your working directory somewhere (**B**)
- (maybe) checkout the first version before the diverged (and before all those single-file copies) and copy your working directory somewhere (**C**)
- checkout `master` again and do `git merge --no-ff --no-commit origRepo/master`
- Do a manual merge (somewhere else):

  - Either do a two-way diff and merge **A** and **B**
  - Or do a three-way merge with **C** as the basis. You can use git to achieve that:

    - start with an empty dir
    - copy in **C**
    - `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "Base"`
    - empty the working dir and copy in **A**
    - `git add -u`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "Local"`
    - `git checkout HEAD^ -b repo`
    - empty the working dir and copy in **B**
    - `git add -u`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "Repo"`
    - `git checkout master`, `git merge repo`
    - Resolve merge conflicts
- Overwrite the contents of your working directory with the results of the external merge and commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help:  I was really wondering what should I have done instead of making these strange merges (partials), Should I have cherry picked some commits from (`origRepo/master`) (but that lets me not choose certain files and so on) and when I want to get all changes I just merge `origRepo/master` into `master`?

Comment: There is no proper way to merge single files. Why do you need to do that in the first place?